# Supabase psql returns deleted data from deleted tables

Tags: postgresql, next.js, supabase

The title: I deleted the data first and then the tables and supabase is still returning the data. Like what? How?

I have this very simple query in `nextJS` using their `api routes`

`const { data, error } = await supabase.from('chats').select('*');`

Comment: Either 1) You did not issue a `commit` after the `DELETE` and  so the values where not actually deleted or 2) You are deleting  the values in one session and looking at the table in another session that started before the `DELETE` so it's snapshot does not see the delete yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I deleted everything from the interface (and they do appear to be deleted). Does your assessment still apply in this case?

Comment: When you boil it down your comment says nothing. You need to add to your question, as text, a complete and detailed of what you did and results you saw when and where.

Comment: 1. I manually deleted the rows from my table and then the table from the `supabase` interface.
2. I queried the table (see code in post above) and the data still appears there. Weird.
3. Looked up maybe its caching it somewhere (browser, nextJS in the "server" somewhere or supabase). Got nothing.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that's all i got. I appreciate your help until now and I still need it :)

Comment: No it is not all you got. You still have not showed the exact commands you used to delete the data. You can also look at the database logs to see what happened at the database. Without this information there is no way to answer the question.

Comment: Set `log_statement = 'all'` in PostgreSQL, so that all statements are logged (while you are debugging this). Then look at the SQL statements that actually drop out of your ORM. That will tell you what really happens. Unless you know that, you won't know how to fix your code.